# File to media migration: use node title for media title

Tags: migrations

I have my files migrated from D7 to D8 (using `d7_file` source plugin to an `entity:file` destination).

I then migrated those files to media (using `file_entity` source plugin to an `entity:media` destination), based off [this post](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/migrating-drupal-7-file-entities-drupal-8-media-entities).

However, the images in my Drupal 7 nodes of which I'm migrating never had alt text. Therefore, I would like to use the Drupal 7 node title as both (a) the Media title and (b) its image alt text.

My files to media migration looks like this (a portion of it):

```
source:
  plugin: file_entity
  type: image
  constants:
    bundle: 'image'
process:
  mid: fid
  bundle: 'constants/bundle'
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    source: language
    default_value: "und"
  # name: filename
  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  status: status
  created: timestamp
  changed: timestamp
  field_media_image/target_id: fid
  # field_media_image/alt: field_file_image_alt_text/0/value
destination:
  plugin: entity:media
```

The commented out lines are what I'd like to use the node title (`name` and `field_media_image/alt`), but I'm not sure how to pull in the original Drupal 7 node title. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your content model, you can't answer this question directly, but what you'll need to do is query your node title for every `fid` entry for your source file entities table. You can do that in many places (e.g. source/process plugin) with your existing source plugin being a good place.

Using your custom `file_entity` source plugin as an example, you'll need to update the `query()` method so  its DB query joins the `node` table based on how you're content is modeled (e.g. entity/paragraph references) then selects the `title` column so it's included in the row data. You can follow that up with updating the `fields()` method so your source plugin will provide the `title` field you need.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like modifying my source plugin is the best option, but a bit over my head. My D7 node type is Business with an image `field_logo`. I'm using Image media in D8 (with `field_media_image`). I'll do some research from here. Thanks again.

Comment: Is that essentially what this source plugin is doing? https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-8-example-pix_migrate/blob/master/src/Plugin/migrate/source/PixImage.php

Comment: It's roughly similar in that it's joining 2 tables to provide one set of migration fields. In your case, you're starting with the `file_managed` table (to pull in all files) then attaching other tables to find associated node data.